# How to compare the date coming from html with oracle database date in jsp

Tags: jsp

I have date of birth filed in my html page.
Based on this  i need to display all employees born on this date.
Ex:

```
<input type="text" value="dob"/> < input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Now  I am parsing the date in my jsp as follows.

```
java.util.Date doj = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm  /yyyy").parse(request.getParameter("dob")); 

out.println(doj);//printing Mon Jul 14 00:08:00 IST 2013

java.sql.Date dt=new java.sql.Date(doj.getTime());

out.println(dt);
//ex:this is giving 2013-07-21.Here I want 21-JUL-2013(as in oracle date format).
```

I need comparison in date format only.

Comment: also, 'as in oracle date format' is wrong by itself, since the oracle date format is so much possible to change upon the environment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer for my question(here instead of inserting I'm fetching data). Thanks  @JB Nizet

```
 String dob = request.getParameter("DOB"):
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
java.util.Date dateOfBirth = formater.parse(dob); 
String sql = "insert into table (dob) value (?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(dateOfBirth.getTime());
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to parse to sql date you can send it as string in correct format. You can apply pattern to your simpleDateFormat object like obj.applyPattern("dd-MMMM-yyyy) it will give you correct formatted date than you can parse it to string.

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSTL  to format the date, so that you can do the comparison on it.

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${doj}" pattern="dd/MMM/yyyy" var="doj" />
<c:if test="${doj eq dob}">
    <doSomeLogic/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ankur Lathi. Now I'got the solution.Below is the exact code what I'm looking for.